# How can I run application using maven instead of iml in idea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, build

In the past I did find out, that there is some checkbox in settings in idea for this...but today i cannot find it. Even in configuration, google or stackoverflow, can you please help me?

To clarify my need: I would like to click on "debug" button, let idea build my projec as maven, start it and I should be able to debug my running application.

Comment: Are you looking for [this option](https://i.imgur.com/dlI2FJW.png)?

Comment: yes, thats it, thank you! I have been in this tab for like 5 time but for some reason I did not notice this checkbox :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven** option can be controlled at File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner:

[image: delegate]